# How to add Javascript "Stop" and "Reset" Button to the following:

Tags: javascript

I need help with adding a stop and reset button for the following count up, so that it doesnt start till you press start, and it doesnt reset unless you press reset, also a stop button would be good! Thanks! cause as you see the buttons i have dont work. Thanks

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script>

var timer;


function startCount()
{
timer = setInterval(count,1);
}
function count()
{
var el = document.getElementById('counter');
var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
el.innerHTML = currentNumber+0.00000003831417624521;

}
</script>
<body onload="startCount();">



<div id="counter">0</div>

<input type="button" value="reset" id="reset" />
<input type="button" value="start" id="start" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, Just a for fun thing im trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
 <script>

 var timer;
 var stop;

 function startCount()
 {
      stop = false;
      timer = setInterval(count,1);
 }
 function stopCount()
 {
      stop = true;
 }
 function count()
 {
      if(stop == false)
          {
           var el = document.getElementById('counter');
           var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
           el.innerHTML = currentNumber+0.00000003831417624521;
      }
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="counter">0</div>

 <input type="button" value="reset" id="reset" onclick="document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 0;" />
 <input type="button" value="start" id="start" onclick="startCount();" />
 <input type="button" value="stop" id="stop" onclick="stopCount();" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

**EDIT** - now includes stop functionality

**NOTE** - I have moved the `<script>` into the `<head>` - All content should either be inside the head or the body.

Comment: Thanks! Now can you add a stop button? Thanks!

Comment: What part are you having difficulty with?  Do you know about **clearInterval**?

Answer (score 0):

```
function stopCount() {
    clearInterval(timer);
}

function resetCount() {
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHtml = 0;
}
```

And use jQuery to attach event listeners to some html element, or if you are never going to get complicated enough to need it, just stick them in the onclick properties as recommended by SimonMayer.